# Mount points and nodev options

Tags: mount

I'm studying device files and I've seen some mount points cannot accept the device file creation (if `nodev` option is set).
Considering my `mount` output:

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
.....
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
```

I've tried to create a device file in `/sys/kernel/debug` (the directory has been chosen only because it doesn't have the `nodev` option) but the operation is not permitted. I don't understand the rationale behind it: why is the operation not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t write to `/sys/kernel/debug` because it’s not a general-purpose file system; it’s the kernel’s [`debugfs`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/debugfs.txt), which exists to allow the kernel to export debug information to user space.

The differences in mount options are caused by whatever mounted the file systems. In your case, I’m guessing they were mounted by systemd. The “core” file systems (`/sys`, `/proc`, `/dev` etc.) are mounted early on in [`src/core/mount-setup.c`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/core/mount-setup.c) (see `mount_table` for details), with `nodev` etc. `/sys/kernel/debug` is mounted by [a separate unit, `sys-kernel-debug.mount`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/units/sys-kernel-debug.mount)
, which doesn’t specify any mount options. I’m not sure there’s any particular rationale behind the difference in mount options.

As to why `nodev` is important, see [Why is "nodev" in /etc/fstab so important? How can character devices be used for hacking?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/188601/86440)

Comment: About `debugfs`: you're right...it is a special filesystem but I don't understand why the `nodev` is not present (as `proc` filesystem or other special filesystems).

Comment: You second link is very interesting and I've tried to re-create the trick described without any result. For example, creating a device driver in `/home` with  `mknod -m 666 usermem c 1, 1` and changing to another user I obtain "operation not permitted". I'm not really sure, but I think this is due to the absence of `CAP_SYS_RAWIO`. Am I right? Do you know some related "attacks"?Any link?

Comment: You’re right, the `/dev/mem` attack is flawed, I’ll revisit that answer tomorrow or Monday.

Comment: About `debugfs`: thanks for your answer...now it's more clear. But how can I know which filesystems support device file creation (and hence the `nodev` option shall be used in order to avoid `mknod`) and which ones not? Do you know any useful link?

Comment: Thanks again for the second link: I'll wait your modifications