# meaning of nodev in mount options on Linux

Tags: linux, mount

Based on google search, what I understood is that the 'nodev' option in mount doesn't allow the creation of device files on a mounted file-system. I tried doing a quick check as follows to see if my understanding is correct, but I found that I am able to create a device file even after doing a mount with 'nodev' option :

```
root@dev16:/home/vagrant# mount -o nodev /dev/sda1 ./mnt-test/
root@dev16:/home/vagrant/mnt-test# ls
bin   dev  initrd.img      lib    lost+found  mnt  proc  run   snap  sys  usr      var      vmlinuz.old
boot  etc  home    initrd.img.old  lib64  media       opt  root  sbin  srv   tmp  vagrant  vmlinuz

root@dev16:/home/vagrant/mnt-test# mknod foobar c 1 5
root@dev16:/home/vagrant/mnt-test# ls -ltr foobar
crw-r--r-- 1 root root 1, 5 Aug  3 06:11 foobar
```

Can anyone please let me know :

1. What is the issue here ?
2. Also let me know how creation of a device file say 'foobar' here would have resulted in a potential security loophole (as the whole point of using nodev option seems to be more security)?
3. From https://haryachyy.wordpress.com/2019/04/17/learning-dpdk-huge-pages/   we have `mount -t hugetlbfs nodev /mnt/huge` , but as per the mount syntax 'nodev' should come with '-o'. Is this syntax correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may still be able to create device nodes, but if the filesystem is mounted with the `nodev` option, any device nodes on that filesystem *won't work.*

For example, let's make a simple image file for a temporary filesystem:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/test.img bs=1024 count=10240
10240+0 records in
10240+0 records out
10485760 bytes (10 MB, 10 MiB) copied, 0.0141206 s, 743 MB/s
$ sudo mke2fs /tmp/test.img
[normal mke2fs messages...]
$ sudo mount -o loop,rw /tmp/test.img /mnt
```

Now we have a temporary extra filesystem (sized 10M) we can use for testing, mounted at `/mnt`.

Let's create a duplicate device node for the second text-mode virtual console, or `/dev/tty2`:

```
$ ls -l /dev/tty2
crw--w---- 1 root tty 4, 2 Aug  4 18:34 /dev/tty2
$ sudo mknod /mnt/hacker_tty c 4 2
$ sudo chown $(whoami) /mnt/hacker_tty
$ ls -l /mnt/hacker_tty
crw-r--r-- 1 my_username root 4, 2 Aug  4 18:46 /mnt/hacker_tty
```

Note that the name of our extra device can be anything: the important thing is that the device type (`c` for character, `b` for block device) and major & minor device numbers (`4` and `2`, respectively) match the target device. These determine which kernel device instance the device node communicates with.

Now, we can write any text we want to the virtual console **without root permissions**:

```
$ printf "I am an evil hacker\nin your computer\ndoing evil things.\n" >/mnt/hacker_tty
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to see the message. Then return to the virtual console where your regular session is, usually either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> depending on your distribution and whether you're using a GUI session or not.

Now, let's unmount the test filesystem, mount it again with the `nodev` mount option, and try that again.

```
$ sudo umount /mnt
$ sudo mount -o loop,rw,nodev /tmp/test.img /mnt
$ printf '\nCurses!\nI have been foiled!\n' >/mnt/hacker_tty
bash: /mnt/hacker_tty: Permission denied
$ ls -l /mnt/hacker_tty
crw-r--r-- 1 my_username root  4, 2 Aug  4 18:46 hacker_tty
```

The visible permissions are unchanged, but the device node just doesn't work.

Even becoming root won't help:

```
$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for my_username:
# printf '\nCurses!\nI have been foiled!\n' >/mnt/hacker_tty
bash: /mnt/hacker_tty: Permission denied
# exit
$
```

Once we've experimented to our satisfaction, let's clean up after ourselves:

```
$ sudo umount /mnt
$ rm /tmp/test.img
```

Note that this was a carefully crafted example that should be relatively harmless. By cloning the device node that matches the block device containing your root filesystem and using a suitable tool to make sense of the filesystem structure, you could, for example, bypass the filesystem permissions and read the contents of `/etc/shadow` (i.e. every user's password hashes!). Or you could just overwrite the block that contains root's password hash, with content of your choice.

---

In `mount -t hugetlbfs nodev /mnt/huge`, the filesystem type `hugetlbfs` does not really need a device associated with it, but the mount command does not know that. As a result, whatever is specified in the "device" parameter, like nodev in your case, is completely ignored.

The writer of [that page](https://haryachyy.wordpress.com/2019/04/17/learning-dpdk-huge-pages/) is simply using `nodev` as a shorthand for "no device" - as a dummy placeholder, completely unrelated to mount options. To actually specify the mount option, you would need `-o nodev`. Yes, it is an unfortunate, confusing choice in a document.

Comment: Yes, like `noexec`, `nodev` doesn’t prevent the creation of certain files, it causes them to “lose” their special properties. For question 2, see [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/188601/86440).

Comment: @StephenKitt : can you please let me know which special properties are lost for `foobar` in the example above and how can i check them (with & without `nodev`) ?

Comment: You created `foobar` as a character device, and the `ls` output shows that it is stored as such on disk; but because of the `nodev` mount option, the kernel won’t act on that and you won’t be able to use it. But that inability is transient: if you remount without `nodev`, the device node will work just fine.

Comment: @StephenKitt : when you say `lose their special properties` OR `you won’t be able to use it`, can you please let me know how can i check that. If possible, can you please elaborate on how to see `foobar` working first (without `nodev` option) and later see the same thing not working (with `nodev`)

Comment: @telcoM : can you please let me know how i can check that the device nodes are not working with `nodev` option (& working without `nodev`)

Comment: I edited my answer to contain an example.

Comment: @telcoM : Thanks for the detailed answer. Can you also let me know something related to point 3 above. From http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html , i see that general syntax for mount command is `mount [-fnrsvw] [-t fstype] [-o options] device dir` while if i see the command for hugepage mount it is `mount -t hugetlbfs nodev /mnt/huge` . This command doesn't have the `device` present and also nodev is present without -o . Can you please help clarify this and let me know if there is any difference in command for mounting virtual filesystems.

Comment: In `mount -t hugetlbfs nodev /mnt/huge`, the filesystem type `hugetlbfs` does not really need a device associated with it, but the mount command does not know it. As a result, whatever is specified in the "device" parameter, like `nodev` in your case, is completely ignored. The writer of that page is simply using `nodev` as a shorthand for "no device" - as a dummy placeholder, completely unrelated to mount options. To actually specify the mount option, you would need `-o nodev`. Yes, it is an unfortunate, confusing choice in a document.

Comment: @telcoM : thanks for the clarification. even the official dpdk documentation ( http://doc.dpdk.org/spp/setup/getting_started.html#mount-hugepages ) uses the same notation for mounting huge pages.